# Why doesn't my border radius transition using tailwind apply?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a tailwind project with a super simple search field so far. When this search field is selected I want the border radius to decrease (make it more square like), apply a color, and some other small things. The transition seems to work for everything except the border-radius.

My markup looks like this:

```
<input
    type="text" 
    className="transition-border duration-500 rounded-full bg-secondary-neutral pl-4 pr-14 py-2 outline-0 focus:border focus:border-accent-neutral focus:rounded-sm focus:bg-white focus:shadow-primary-extra-light focus:shadow-md text-sm text-ellipsis w-full max-w-sm"
    placeholder="Søk etter produkter, merker og mer"
/>
```

I've also added this to my tailwind config to get border transition:

```
transitionProperty: {
    'border': 'border,border-radius,box-shadow,background-color',
},
```

The relevant generated css for the input field looks like this:

```
.duration-500 {
    transition-duration: 500ms;
}
.transition-border {
    transition-property: border,border-radius,box-shadow,background-color;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```

What am I missing to get the animation on the border radius as well?

Comment: This is not so obvious but it happens because `rounded-full` class generates `border-radius: 9999px`. If you will be more specific in radius it will [work](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Cqbyq5ANKR) - I've created two minimal examples, one with input and one with simple figure

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your question is provided here :-

```
<input
type="text" 
class="transition-border duration-500 rounded-full bg-secondary-neutral pl-4 pr-14 py-2 outline-0 focus:border focus:border-accent-neutral focus:rounded-sm focus:bg-white focus:shadow-primary-extra-light focus:shadow-md text-sm text-ellipsis w-full max-w-sm card"
placeholder="Søk etter produkter, merker og mer" />


@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


.card {
  @apply relative flex items-center justify-center w-80 shadow- 
  [0_10px_20px_rgba(0,0,0,0.2)] overflow-hidden transition-all duration- 
  [0.5s] ease-[cubic-bezier(0.23,1,0.320,1)]  rounded-[10px] border-2                                     
  border-solid border-primary-light hover:shadow- 
  [0_0_20px_rgba(9,117,241,0.8)] hover:border-secondary-light dark:bg-white;
  background: #0000;
}
```